# Unexpected results when filtering security alerts by createdDateTime

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-security

I'm seeing some unexpected behavior from the Microsoft Graph Security Alerts APIin the Graph API.

When filtering by `createdDateTime`, when no results are expected, it is returning results for today instead of an empty array (as expected).

```
/beta/security/alerts?$filter=createdDateTime ge 2020-07-26T18:09:31Z
```

If the filter is changed to `eventDateTime`, the expected empty array is returned:

```
/beta/security/alerts?$filter=eventDateTime ge 2020-07-26T18:09:31Z
```

I'm seeing this on multiple accounts, but not in the Graph API Explorer.
This happens in the beta as well as v1.0 API.

Answer (score 0):

Please reach out to us at graphsecfeedback_at_microsoft_dot_com with your tenant ID and json alerts seen for the createdDateTime filter query so that we can investigate further.